# PopupMenu freezing parent frame

Tags: java, awt, frame, repaint, popupmenu

I'm using a AWT PopupMenu on a frame that constantly repaints (it's a game), but whenever the PopupMenu shows, the parent frame freezes. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Is this a Swing or an AWT application? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the rest of the application is in made in Swing and you are using the AWT popmenu in combination with Swing components.

I've had my fair share of AWT PopMenu problems. Do you need to show the Popmenu outside the bounds of your application ? If you only need to be able to show it inside your application (JFrame) you are probably beter off with just putting a JComponent on top of all your other panels (with a JLayredPane) and draw your own pop menu there.

Even easier is to use JLayer in Java 7 for the same effect (or JXLayer if your not on Java 7 but on Java 5 or 6).

The above method is also way more powerful then the AWT popmenu because you control the drawing. So for example making it translucent or giving it round edges becomes a breeze.

Comment: I'm only using AWT component :) Not sure, but the above is not possible in AWT, right?

Comment: I don't know; I never had a reason to use AWT directly. Are you using AWT + Java 2D for your game ? I guess you are working with Graphics2D objects to do the drawing ? Could you gives use some additional information about what you are doing ?

Comment: I'm using a Graphics object to paint directly on a (undecorated) frame

Comment: Have you tried using Swing instead of AWT directly ? Put your paint methods in JComponent.paintComponent(Graphics g) which you put in an undecorated JFrame. Then use a JPopupMenu instead of its AWT counter part and see if that works. I dont think many people are able to help you if you use AWT directly since most people dont use AWT directly (to my humble knowledge). For native components people tend to use SWT instead of AWT. For everything else there is JavaFX and Swing, but using AWT directly is not something I see very often.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer sticking with AWT as much as possible :) I've also tried showing the PopupMenu on a different Frame, but the first Frame still freezes..

Comment: I'm now using JPopupMenu directly on the AWT Frame, and it works great. Would still like to find out why PopupMenu blocks everything though

Comment: Great to hear! But you should keep your eyes open when mixing Heavy weight (AWT) and light weight (Swing) components. The combination can sometimes behave unpredictably.